# AWS Cloud9 with Angular 9

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, aws-cloud9

My developing laptop just broke down and I launched and cloud9 EC2 instance on AWS. 
I can compile my angular 9 without any problems.
`ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8080 --disable-host-check`
But when I click then on preview I get this message in the browser: `Oops
VFS connection does not exist`
Also, if I try to open up in a new tab, it loads for ever and at some point he gives me the error of: `took to long to respond`. The url is some ipv4:8080
Any idea what I need to configure?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to disable Ad Blockers and Privacy Extensions? It may help.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is still struggling with this, the trick is to open up 4200 in your EC2 firewall (security group).

Please note the security implications of doing this.

Here is the article that solved it for me: https://jorgeavante.com/posts/running-an-angular-project-in-aws-cloud9/

Answer (score 0):

The only way I managed to get it to work was using ngrok, which forwards your http request to your ec2 instance. 
Not a clean solution, but its working. https://ngrok.com/